# Get selected range in all sheets of a spreadsheet using Google App Script for Workspace add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace-add-ons

I would like to get all the selected ranges in all the sheets of my spreadsheet through an unbound Google App script for a Workspace add-on.

For example, I have three sheets - A (active), B and C.

I have selected the following:

1. A1:B5 in sheet A
2. B3 in sheet B
3. B2:B8 and D1:D4 in sheet C

I would like to get the selections for all the sheets, like this:

```
A A1:B5
B B3
C B2:B8
C D1:D4
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
// gets all sheets - working fine
var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();

for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {

  let sheet = sheets[i]

  // prints sheet name - working fine
  console.log(sheet.getName()) 

  var rangeList = sheet.getActiveRangeList().getRanges();

  for (let range in rangeList) {
    console.log(sheet.getName(), range.getA1Notation())
  }
}
```

This is the output I'm getting:

```
A A1:B5
B A1:B5
C A1:B5
```

Comment: Looks like an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/115931946) that is open for 2 years...

Comment: Tried `getSelection()`?

Comment: Yes! 

`getSelection()`   

returns the selection for the active sheet as mentioned in the first line of the [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/selection)

Comment: @RemcoE33, looks like it! :( Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@RemcoE33](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13461183/remcoe33) mentioned, it seems that selecting ranges from multiple spreadsheets is only returning the first selected range as stated in the [Issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/115931946). As of now there is no workaround to this behavior and is still an ongoing problem.